# Different Carthage options for each dependency?

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode7, dependency-management, carthage

I have a dependency in my `Cartfile` that I'd like to treat differently. Is it possible to run Carthage with options for one dependency, but different for another?

For example, here is my `Cartfile`:

```
github "ninjaprox/NVActivityIndicatorView"
github "nickoneill/PermissionScope"
github "Skyscanner/SkyFloatingLabelTextField"
```

Can I run `carthage update --platform iOS` for `NVActivityIndicatorView` and `SkyFloatingLabelTextField`, but use `carthage update --no-build --platform iOS` for `PermissionScope`? How about if it is possible I exclude a dependency from my Cartfile, but run it directly from the command line instead?